# Ionic 5 Google Map Marker breaking animations on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, animation, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I'm adding google map on an ionic app using google maps javascript api 3. The map works fine but the minute i add marker on the map, the cordova animations stop working on ios, on android everything works smoothly. For example clicking on ion-select or adding Alert produces following error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: – "undefined is not a function (near
>    '...element.animate...')" – "; Zone:" – "" – "; Task:" –
>    "Promise.then" – "; Value:" (2) TypeError: undefined is not a function
>    (near '...element.animate...') —
>
> ```
>  animation-5559213c.js:652 (anonymous function) — 
>  animation-5559213c.js:652 forEach initializeWebAnimation — 
>  animation-5559213c.js:651   initializeAnimation —
>  animation-5559213c.js:674 play — animation 5559213c.js:950 (anonymous
>  function) — 
>  animation-5559213c.js:961 forEach play —
>  animation-5559213c.js:960 (anonymous function) —
>  animation-5559213c.js:852 ZoneAwarePromise — zone.js:910 playAsync —
>  animation-5559213c.js:850 (anonymous function) —
>  overlays-10cf2041.js:202 step — tslib.es6.js:99 fulfilled —
>  tslib.es6.js:70 run — zone.js:150 (anonymous function) — zone.js:889
>  runTask — zone.js:195 drainMicroTaskQueue — 
>  zone.js:601 promiseReactionJob
> ```

My app's ionic version is 5.2.3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have to add the polyfill for it. Run ```npm install --save web-animations-js``` then uncomment ```// import 'web-animations-js';``` in the ```polyfills.ts``` file

Comment: Your solution worked for me bro. If you can post the answer i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import the *web-animations-js* [polyfill](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills).

Run `npm install --save web-animations-js` in the terminal then uncomment the following line in *src/polyfills.ts*:

`import 'web-animations-js';`